# angular2 Implementing FullCalendar-Scheduler with PrimeNG-Scheduler - Resources are not showing

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, fullcalendar, primeng

FullCalendar has an add-on called Scheduler which I am trying to use with PrimeNG-Schedule component. Looking at the PrimeNG docs, there is an 'options' property that I can use to send arbitrary information to FullCalendar.

I am adding resources but still i am not able to see any resources on the calendar. i can only see events without any resources.

I would appreciate any help

```
    <p-schedule 
    [events]="myevents" 
    [header]="header" 
    [options]="optionConfig"
    >
</p-schedule>
```

**Component**

```
    ngOnInit() {

   this.resources=[
      { id: 'a', title: 'Room A'},
      { id: 'b', title: 'Room B', eventColor: 'green',"start": "2018-05-01" },
      { id: 'c', title: 'Room C', eventColor: 'orange',"start": "2018-05-01" },
      { id: 'd', title: 'Room D', eventColor: 'red',"start": "2018-05-01" }
  ];

      this.myevents = [
        { id: '1', resourceId: 'a', start: '2018-04-06', end: '2018-04-08', title: 'event 1' },
        { id: '2', resourceId: 'a', start: '2018-04-07T09:00:00', end: '2018-04-07T14:00:00', title: 'event 2' },
        { id: '3', resourceId: 'b', start: '2018-04-07T12:00:00', end: '2018-04-08T06:00:00', title: 'event 3' },
        { id: '4', resourceId: 'c', start: '2018-04-07T07:30:00', end: '2018-04-07T09:30:00', title: 'event 4' },
        { id: '5', resourceId: 'd', start: '2018-04-07T10:00:00', end: '2018-04-07T15:00:00', title: 'event 5' }
    ];

this.optionConfig = {
        "resources": this.resources
        }

}
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work. Everything seems good but you will only see the resources when you are in timeline based modes https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline-view

Comment: So figured out what the issue was ? I am planning on doing this myself and currently searching for possible issues.